# How to use a CSV file from an oscilloscope for further analysis

Tags: power-electronics, oscilloscope, datasheet, time, timing-analysis

I saved and opened this data from my oscilloscope:

[image]

How to plot the real scale waveform data? Do I have to multiply it with vertical scale?

And what about the time? What to do if I want to plot the waveform data in the time domain? Since there's no time data and all I have is the sample period, horizontal scale and position.

here's the waveform from the oscilloscope display
[image: Screenshot from oscilloscope display]

Thanks!!

Comment: It might help if you show a picture of the scope display also.

Comment: You right! will you kindly check my edit? @Andyaka

Comment: Why don't you just plot a graph in excel and it will all become absolutely clear.

Comment: The X axis will be the number of sample 1-500. I want to plot it in time domain, can I?

Comment: Make a graph in your spreadsheet. This site isn't for teaching how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Just use your eyes and brain and look at what you see: -

[image]

Then using excel (that's where your data appears to be) plot a graph of that data. This site isn't here to teach anyone how to use excel (or a spreadsheet) so that bit is up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for PulseView (sigrok). A cross-platform program for all kinds of formats and it's very fast (even with a 1MB csv), quick zooms, multiple channels/columns, math, very simple, much better than Excel for viewing. You might have to adjust the CSV header though to import it (single line header and the import format specs set to "t,a").

Answer (score 0):

> How to plot the real scale waveform data? Do I have to multiply it
> with vertical scale?

You can do that, or use another factor based on scope probe attenuation or other factors that make sense for your ultimate objective.

> And what about the time? What to do if I want to plot the waveform data in the time domain? Since there's no time data and all I have is the sample period, horizontal scale and position.

The sample period should give you what you need.